# Best way to link to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are wanting to establish a process that would allow users to email a central email address such as help@abccompany.com with their support case and that request would then automatically be uploaded to a sharepoint list. What is the best way to accomplish this? We are users of SharePoint Online but not Outlook 365.

Expanded Question:

we have a central email address help@abccompany.com and instead of using a users submitting their support requests through sharepoint form via powerapps, forms, or InfoPath forms and that information being pushed to a list the users would email the central email address with their support request and that information would automatically be pushed to the SharePoint list. We are wanting to know if this is possible?

Comment: Do you have access to Microsoft Flow?